# Twilio,Not able to make changes in live call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I have  three functionalities to do-

1-Hold the call

2-Unhold the call

3-transfer the call

How can I do it without using conference.Also I am creating the call using the REST API.

Comment: Using conference is the easiest way as there are APIs to hold and unhold. If you want to see how to achieve this with a normal call, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41240344/28376

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twilio retrieve call on hold back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41236926/twilio-retrieve-call-on-hold-back)