# how to handle call disconnection while call is on hold (queued)

Tags: twilio

I am following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41240344/3964095) to work on hold and resume of a call from the virtual caller's end. It works but I am facing two more issues. FYI, the setup is exactly same.

First:

The first round of Hold, Resume works perfectly. On Hold, I pass the CallSid, then I apply the `<Enqueue>` TwiMl to the child calls (only one would be here in my case).

```
  client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: callId }).then(calls => {
    calls.forEach(call => {
      call
      .update({ twiml: '<Response><Enqueue>ADMIN_ID</Enqueue></Response>' });
    });
  });
```

And on Resume, I update the Sid of the Caller to Dial again from the queue

```
  client
    .calls(callId)
    .update({ twiml: '<Response><Dial action="/holding"><Queue>ADMIN_ID</Queue></Dial></Response>' })
```

It works perfectly foe the first round. When I hit the `hold` for the second time, it says `We are sorry, some application error occurred. Good Bye!` at the caller end and disconnects. At the receiver end, it goes to playing hold music. What am I doing wrong?

Second:

I see that setting `action` in the `<Dial>` keeps it alive and repeats the action TwiMl in my case. But in a normal scenario without any `hold`, if the receiver disconnects, I as the caller keeps hearing the action repeatably and the call doesn't hang up. Also while on hold, if the caller or callee hangs up the other one just keeps stuck in the current state. Is there any way to fix this with the above setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using REST API checks for status of the calls.

```
  client.calls.list({ parentCallSid: callId }).then(calls => {
    calls.forEach(call => {

      if (call.status !== 'in-progress') {
        client
          .calls(callId)
          .update({ status: 'completed' })
      }
    });
  });
```

F.e. the above code checks if the parent Sid (virtual caller) is disconnected and in that case it disconnects the child call.

Comment: This all sounds good. Is there anything not working any more?

Comment: @philnash No, I made it work with the mentioned appraoch.

Comment: Great news! Glad you got it sorted and thanks for sharing the answer!